# Why/How type convertion through dynamic type in C# 4.0 works

Tags: c#-4.0

I had this situation and found that code bellow solves the problem.
I would like to know why it works.

Suppose I have the following situation:

```
int i = 2;
object o = (object)i;
decimal d = (decimal)o;
```

This will fail with invalid cast exception

While code bellow will work:

```
int i = 2;
object o = (object)i;
dynamic dyn = o;
decimal d = (decimal)dyn;
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cast in the first example fails because there's no conversion operator defined between `object` and `decimal`; the underlying value of `o` being a type that *does* have a conversion operator makes no difference because the runtime is only working with the types of the operands.

In the second example the conversion of `dyn` to `decimal` includes an extra step where the DLR  figures out the underlying type of `dyn`, using (I'm guessing) its value. Because it uses the value to determine the type it ends up using `int`, and can therefore bind to the defined `int` - `decimal` conversion operator.